# Issues in Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying since long in one query by checking same fields. My query is like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.products_id,products_description.products_title, products_sizes.size_id, products_sizes.size_title,products_sku.sku     
FROM products_description
LEFT JOIN products ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sizes ON products_description.products_id = products_sizes.products_id
LEFT JOIN product_stock_history ON product_stock_history.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sku ON products_sku.size_id = products_sizes.size_id
WHERE products.enable_stock_management = '1'
AND products.products_id != '-11'
```

this retrieves result like below

[image]

But i would like to retrieve the details like below by checking whether sizeid is different then only display, else retrieve the first record

[image]

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: you can use `group by  products.products_id,products_description.products_title, products_sizes.size`

Comment: group by does not work?

Comment: yeah, that will work. oh , that din't came to my mind. Group by for only products_sizes.size will work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work as you expects

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.products_id,
                products_description.products_title,
                products_sizes.size_id,
                products_sizes.size_title,
                products_sku.sku
FROM products_description
LEFT JOIN products ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sizes ON products_description.products_id = products_sizes.products_id
LEFT JOIN product_stock_history ON product_stock_history.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sku ON products_sku.size_id = products_sizes.size_id
WHERE products.enable_stock_management = '1'
  AND products.products_id != '-11'
GROUP BY size_id,
         size_title
```

Comment: I not tested the query because I do not have my computer were

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT products.products_id,products_description.products_title, products_sizes.size_id, products_sizes.size_title,products_sku.sku     
FROM products_description
LEFT JOIN products ON products_description.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sizes ON products_description.products_id = products_sizes.products_id
LEFT JOIN product_stock_history ON product_stock_history.products_id = products.products_id
LEFT JOIN products_sku ON products_sku.size_id = products_sizes.size_id
WHERE products.enable_stock_management = '1'
AND products.products_id != '-11'GROUP BY products.products_id;
```